# wsl check if we are on a remote ssh session

Tags: linux, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using a remote PC WSL (Ubuntu 20) as development server and as part of my work flow I would like to automate the download of files when I build an app while on a ssh session.

So I need to find a way to know if I am running scripts (NodeJS) directly in the machine or remotely while connected via ssh.

Is there a way to check this?

For extra info:

- I authenticate myself using Public/private Keys
- the allow user in ssh and my local user name are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following checks may still work in WSL:

- If one of the variables `SSH_CLIENT` or `SSH_TTY` is defined
- If the login shell's parent process name is `sshd`

Answer (score 1):

If the ssh server is running inside windows and not wsl itself, from wsl you will need to escape into cmd and check.

This is what I came up with:

```
echo $(cmd.exe /c 'echo %SSH_CLIENT%' 2>/dev/null | sed $'s/\r//' | grep ' 22$')
```